# How to make string into permutation?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

So the assignment I was given was to create a function that takes x as an argument which assigns numbers according to (what I assume to be) the inputted letter's ordinal values. Keep in mind that only non-repeating lowercase letters are to be inputted.

Since "a < b", and "a < c", if I were to input a string "abc" into this function, it should return '123'. If I inputted "zad", it should return "312". In other words, smallest letter starts at 1, the next smallest, 2, etc.

How should I go about construction a function that fits this criteria? I figured I would include a range going from ord[a] to ord [z] and then include an elif loop statement. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a dictionary that maps each character to its position in the sorted list of the distinct characters in the original string:

```
def perm(s):
    indexes = {x:i+1 for i,x in enumerate(sorted(set(s)))}
    return ''.join(str(indexes[x]) for x in s)

print(perm('abc'))
print(perm('zad'))
```

Comment: you can use the `start` keyword argument for `enumerate` to avoid `i+1`. `enumerate(sorted(s), start=1)`

Comment: meant to comment before I deleted my answer -- I'm dumb and misunderstood the question. Your answer is perfect, great job!

Comment: True, explains why you are so quick to overlook my response.

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = "bca"
print (sorted([str1.index(x)+1 for x in sorted(str1)]))
```

Sort them first and print sorted index of them. Carefull, +1 to index, because index starting from `0`.

Comment: what if str1 = "bbca"?

Comment: `str.index` is slow. A better way to do this is to use `enumerate` as @JuanLopes has done

Comment: @JuanLopes True, I didn't realized that.